# user add drop pin, Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, geolocation

We are creating a online app to let users add pins to google maps. Please see

How can we add a location by user click? I imagine a user is adding a location by left/right clicking, a pin in dropped and a box appears over map, then user enters some info about that location.

Name
Address
Store Contact
Store Manager
Email
Website
Notes

I want google maps to drop a pin, geolocate position, pass info to database and store user input about location.

Answer (score 3):

Use these steps:

1. When User clicks on a map create a Marker

   **google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(event) {
                   addMarker to the map;
               });**
2. When User clicks on a Marker Open infowindow with a form congaing fields to get the data and a submit button.

   **google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
               Open the infowindow;
           });**
3. When User clicks on submit button, save the data along with longitude, latitude to the database